# Why is $|\text{dist}(x,M)-\text{dist}(y,M)|\leq d(x,y)|$ for all $x,y\in X$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Show that for $M\subset X$, $M\neq
>  \emptyset$: $|\text{dist}(x,M)-\text{dist}(y,M)|\leq d(x,y)$ for alle
>   $x,y\in X$.

I know that $\text{dist}(\cdot, M): X\to [0,\infty), \text{dist}(x,M):=\underset{y\in M} \inf d(x,y)$. So we have:$$|\text{dist}(x,M)-\text{dist}(y,M)|=\left |\underset{y\in M} \inf d(x,y)-\underset{x\in M} \inf d(x,y) \right |$$ How can I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall x, y \in X$, we have $$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathrm{dist}(x,M)\leqslant d(x,a)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,a) \text{ for all }a\in M\\
\implies& \mathrm{dist}(x,M)-d(x,y)\leqslant \inf\limits_{a\in M} d(y,a)=\mathrm{dist}(y,M)\\
\implies &\mathrm{dist}(x,M)-\mathrm{dist}(y,M)\leqslant d(x,y).
\end{aligned}
$$
Simlarly, $$\mathrm{dist}(y,M)-\mathrm{dist}(x,M)\leqslant d(x,y).$$
Therefore $$
\left|\mathrm{dist}(x,M)-\mathrm{dist}(y,M)\right|\leqslant d(x,y).
$$